# Does SharePoint 2010 support the iCalendar format?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, icalendar

Sounds like a very silly question, but I tried, and it isn't too easy to find a simple answer to this simple question on google.

---

The longer story:

Before I started my search, I just took it for granted that SharePoint provides a web service to access a calendar using iCal.

But after having [searched](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint%20ical%20support) I fear I was totally wrong. I just don't want to believe it. Not even in SharePoint 2010? Twelve years after the standard was [published](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445)?!

I found a [blog](http://aspnetguru.wordpress.com/2007/06/01/understanding-the-sharepoint-calendar-and-how-to-export-it-to-ical-format/) about implementing an iCal export, but to be honest, implementing it clean, complete and bugfree, and ideally even two-way is just too much of an effort to start before asking here.

I also found a [commercial product called MashPoint](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/mashpoint/archive/2009/01/26/sharepoint-support-for-icalendar-and-vcard-using-the-mashpoint-rest-api.aspx), but it's overkill.

The tiny remaining spark of hope makes me put this as a SO question and hope that after the coffee, the whole world looks different all of a sudden.

Comment: Hm. You're right - not easy to find out. I'll watch this question :-)

Comment: @Lars: You may not be very lucky, I posted it in April and never got a single response...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint does support iCalanders. I am currently using on an events list so people can save to their outlook.

You can download the .ics based on the url like so:

```
http://yoursite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=%7BListID%7D&CacheControl=1&ID=1&Using=event.ics
```

Replacing yoursite with your host name, ListID with the ID of your list with the events and the ID=1 with whatever list item number you want.

In SharePoint designer you can implement into the page as a hyperlink like the following example:

```
http://yoursite/Marketing/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&amp;Cmd=Display&amp;List=%7BA742AAC4%2D2654%2D4E64%2D9280%2D7813D2A343A2%7D&amp;CacheControl=1&amp;ID={$thisNode/@ID}&amp;Using=event.ics
```

I'm not sure about a direct web service to retrieve the iCal if you want to use pragmatically but i'm sure you can just use this URL and a stream reader to save or manipulate.

Comment: Thank you! Does it support read-only or can you also send event/updates to SharePoint using iCal? That would enable syncing your iPhone calendar with SharePoint, for example.

Comment: This method is read only. If you want a more interactive style have a look at subscribing to a SharePoint calendar in outlook which will keep events updated. Otherwise there are a few code solutions out there to sync outlook and SharePoint.

Comment: Two years old question, today I realize I did not properly differentiate between iCal and CalDav. I guess what I was looking for was a CalDav interface. But given the question as I asked it back then this looks like a perfect answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "RSS Feed" option in the "Calendar Tools" section to help find the correct url. Each item in the RSS feed will have an event.ics generated by the owssvr.dll, which you can then convert to the format described by kravitz88 to get an ics for the whole calendar.

[image: Sharepoint ICS]

If your original URL was something like this:

http://SHAREPOINT.local/siateam/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx

Then inside the RSS item links should look something like this:

[http://SHAREPOINT.local/siateam/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Cmd=Display&CacheControl=1&List={df83eb1b-0403-42ec-8198-ec523bf1acc1}&ID=254&Using=%2Fsiateam%2FLists%2FCalendar/event.ics](http://SHAREPOINT.local/siateam/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Cmd=Display&CacheControl=1&List=%7Bdf83eb1b-0403-42ec-8198-ec523bf1acc1%7D&ID=254&Using=/siateam/Lists/Calendar/event.ics)

Answer (score 0):

Again, maybe not a very direct way of exporting to iCalendar, but this may help to get there anyway. I found on Sharepoint 2007 (and I am not sure whether 2010 has this feature, too, but it's quite possible), that you can create your own views of a calendar by using the "View" button and menu:

1. Create View
2. Datasheet View
3. Give the view a name in the "View Name" field, and select all the fields you want to export in the list below.
4. Once you have the new datasheet view, this should show all events in the entire calendar in one single (scrollable) table.
5. Select everything (Ctrl-A), and copy and paste...

I found that MS Excel 2013 for some reason doesn't want to paste the contents of the clipboard thus obtained, but LibreOffice Calc does it just fine without any complaints. The specific calendar I exported in that way had some 1,300 events spread out over five years.

6. Convert the table thus obtained to iCalendar format... (I haven't done that yet, but that should be the easy part; may have to read the standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545 )

Comment: Thank you. The question was whether SharePoint has an iCal API. As the question was already answered by kravits and Greg, both presenting ways to get the URL for an iCal API, what value does your newly added answer add?

Answer (score 0):

**Single Calendar Event in iCalendar (iCal/CalDav) format**

Open SharePoint calender event, click on the 'Custom Commands' tab and click 'Export Event'. You will be prompted to save a file of '.ics' type - this is the iCalendar compatible file and once opened will work with all calendar clients.

[image]