# How to get Ical URL for whole Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint

I have events list in share point and i want to generate an Ical URl to use it in another application as feed to show events.

I have tried solution posted here by @kravits88

[Does SharePoint 2010 support the iCalendar format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513240/does-sharepoint-2010-support-the-icalendar-format#)

but by mentioned method i am able to create Ical URL for individual event (list item). Is it possible to get the URL for whole list items (all events) ?

Answer (score 0):

As the linked post in your question points out, there is no native capability within SharePoint to export an entire Calendar list in iCal format; only individual list items (i.e. events). For SharePoint 2007, the Community Kit for SharePoint group includes a feature that can be deployed, as described in the [Blog post here](http://aspnetguru.wordpress.com/2007/06/01/understanding-the-sharepoint-calendar-and-how-to-export-it-to-ical-format/) & [downloaded here](http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/4234). You'd need to check about support for newer versions of SharePoint.

Alternatively, if you want to consume this data in other 3rd party apps & leverage native MS routes, you would either need to work with the RSS feed output SharePoint provides, or build upon their STSSync protocol, as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd587524.aspx). That protocol can be used to export an entire Calendar list; it was purpose built for Outlook integration & requires ActiveX though, so it may not be viable for you.

Also mentioned in the linked post, there are commercial products that can be used; I have experience with one that includes an API for querying & aggregating SharePoint data that can then be transformed (via XSLT 2.0) into iCal format for consumption in 3rd party apps.

Comment: Thank you Stevangelista for your response. I am going on ur suggested solutions and I will see if one of them works out. I am thinking also of ability to convert the RSS feed to updated iCal URl feed. any idea ?

Comment: Again, you would need some mechanism for doing said conversion. The API for SharePoint that I work with makes it trivial to do so server-side via XSLT 2.0; you can either explore that route or do the data transformation on your end after having consumed the raw data from SharePoint.